# Who did Marcy D'Arcy sleep with at the end of "The naked and the Dead, but mostly the naked"?

Tags: plot-explanation, married-with-children

At the end of the Married with Children episode "The naked and the Dead, but Mostly the Naked", the show shows the houses of Al, Ike and Bobby with off-screen screams of pleasure from their respective wives. However, Marcy didn't scream out "Oh Jefferson", but "Oh, Mister Lincoln". I seriously doubt that, even with his past, Jefferson would have managed to get the corpse of Abraham Lincoln exhumed for his wife to defile.

So, who did she sleep with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the guys brought their wives to the strip club in that episode, Jefferson wore a false Lincoln beard. He explains to Marcy that he's disguised to keep his reputation intact, but in fact, he doesn't want to be recognized because he frequents this club a lot and told Marcy otherwise. Later on, the Lincoln beard serves as an erection joke when an especially buxom stripper performs. **The end of the episode implies that Jefferson simply kept the beard on when he was forced to pleasure his wife.**

[image: still from the episode]

Comment: Ah, beat me to it with a better answer!

Comment: Thanks. The byproduct of seeing this show WAY too many times (damn reruns!).

Comment: It's been like 14 years or so ago since I saw that episode. I totally forgot about that beard. here, have 25 points.